# I want to add max value to my model field based on the data of another model which is related to it through one to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

[Image of django admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2edNQ.png)

This are my two models:

```
class English(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    totalMarks = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.topic}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "English"


class EnglishMarks(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(UserField, on_delete=CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey(English, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="marks")
    marks = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(English.objects.first().totalMarks),MinValueValidator(0)])
```

I want the marks field of **EnglishMarks** Model to not exceed the value of totalMarks field  of related data of **English** Model.

**Note:** I am using Inlines to populate **EnglishMarks table** while creating new data in **English table**

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: My current code will set max_value to the value totalMarks of first row of English model if it exists. But I want to set it equal to the value of totalMarks of the data which is related to that entry not the first row.